# python script to open windows command prompt and print some strings

Tags: python

I have a scenario where I have **3 python script files**.
Using one file I will create a text file. Using the other two script files, I will append some strings to the file which I have created earlier. So far, it's working good.

But, I need to do the same in a different way now. I need to open a **command prompt**, then print the strings on that command prompt, **using two python script files.**

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well, we can help if you explain what the problem is. Don't you know how to open a command prompt or run a python script there? If so: Have you tried to google "How to run a python script in command line"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're using windows so I'll attempt to answer your question with that assumption. If I understand what you're trying to accomplish you have 1 script to launch the command prompt, then you want to launch the other 2 scripts and redirect output to the command line. Because you're really light on the details all I can give you is some pretty generic stuff with the easy way being something like this:

```
import subprocess
# Opens cmd.exe and pipes stdout
p1 = subprocess.Popen('cmd', shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Runs python scripts using stdin and stdout from p1
p2 = subprocess.Popen('python.exe foo.py', shell=True, stdin=p1.stdout)
p3 = subprocess.Popen('python.exe bar.py', shell=True, stdin=p1.stdout)
p1.stdout.close()
p2.communicate()
p3.communicate()
```

Another option would be to allow arguments so you would run the initial script like this:

```
python main.py foo.py bar.py
```

Without a more specific question that's about as good an answer as I can come up with.

Comment: Let me know if that worked and, if so, mark it as answered please.